# Better way to create objects with dependencies in PHP

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I am currently working on a PHP project where I need to create objects of a class `RelevantClass`. I am using Dependency Injection via DI Container.

### Underlying Structure

Let's suppose I have the following class structure:

```
class SomeServiceClass {
   
}

class EntityClass {

}

class RelevantClass {

    /**
    * @Inject
    */
    private SomeServiceClass $service

    public function __construct(EntityClass $entity){
        $this->service = inject(SomeServiceClass::class)
        $this->entity = $entity;
    }

    public function someMethod() : void
    {
        ...
        $this->service->doSomething($this->entity);
        $this->entity->doSomething();
        ...
    }
}
```

The issue here is that my `EntityClass`Object needs to be modified by my `RelevantClass`, as in I can't pass in an injected instance of `EntityClass` into the constructor of `RelevantClass`.

The Service class includes some helper methods and other functionality, so it can be injected directly.

**Now my question is, how should I instantiate my `RelevantClass` class?**

### Approach 1

The way it works right now is that I simply call the constructor:

```
$entity = ... # Getting the entity from the database

$relevantObject = RelevantClass($entity); # here my service is instantiated by explicitly calling the di container

$relevantObject->someMethod();
```

That way, my Service is set by the constructor via injection container and my entity is passed through the constructor argument.

### Approach 2

Although it is working, I am wondering if it were better practice if I structured my RelevantClass in a way that allows me to instantiate it via DI Container, too?

```
$entity = ... # Getting the entity from the database

$relevantObject = inject(RelevantClass::class); # this would inject my service class as well
$relevantObject->setEntity($entity);
$relevantObject->someMethod();
```

Briefly summed up, `someMethod` needs `SomeServiceClass` to perform some operations on an `EntityClass` instance. `SomeServiceClass` can be injected, while `EntityClass` cannot.

What is the way to go here? I am aware that both approaches woudl work, but which one of them would be best practice? The project I am currently working on barely uses the constructor to instantiate classes, so I am wondering, whether there are any inherent advantages to the second approach?